# Best way to approach users voting on and identifying content?

Tags: 7

I am working on a Drupal 7 website, [Double Enders](http://www.doubleenders.com), where users can view and add individual boats, categorizing them by design.

I already have several boats that have not been identified by their design. I am planning on using views to allow users to view the boats that do not have designs associated with them. I would like to also give users a drop-down menu with all the designs (which is a view that I use elsewhere in the site) and allow them to use this drop-down menu to identify/vote on what type of design the boat is, tallying their votes.

Looking through the voting modules, it does not appear that any of them allow one to use a view as the options a user can select between. Instead, they all seem to provide some variation on ratings or yes/no.

I am considering using the Voting API module to build the functionality myself. However, before I go down that road, I was wondering if I had missed a module that I could use or another way to get the functionality I desire. Does anyone have any suggestions, or am I right to proceed using the Voting API module?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module. It supports [adding fields to a flag](https://www.drupal.org/node/917576), so a user could first flag a boat ("I can identify that design!") and then select one of the known designs on the flagging form.

Whatever you end up using, I'd like to read what you choose, and why!